# How to append a file name in unix with a String and Current Date

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have 4 names (AA,BB,CC,DD) in a config file. This has been used in a script.

I am trying to get the output to be saved as

```
Source_Server_Path="/dev/FtpData_Files/START_STOP_"$1"_"$Current_Date""
```

where `$1` will be any one in the names.

`$Current_Date` has to be in the format 05Jun2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample script/method ... Try if it helps

**config.txt**

```
AA,BB,CC,DD
```

**Script.sh**

```
file=$1
config=`cat $file | awk -F "," '{print $1}'` 
#It will take AA .. whatever parameter you pass
Current_Date=`date +%d%b%Y`
echo START_STOP_"$config"_"$Current_Date"
```

**How to run**

```
 sh script.sh config.txt
```

**Output**

```
START_STOP_AA_07Jun2013
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ foo="/bar/quux/$(date +%d%b%Y)"
$ echo "${foo}"
/bar/quux/07Jun2013
```

See also `man date`.